# SharePoint forms customization

Tags: css, sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-designer

When creating a List in SharePoint, I can customize the forms using InfoPath to change fonts, colors and add Rules and Actions for only the part of editing not the whole form.
I need to customize the appearance and access the form's stylesheet to change the rest of the form's background color and add logo so that the appearance reflects the whole form not just the part of editing.

Any ideas... ?

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint designer also you can customize the form. It allows you to create your own form as well as few are already there like New Item form, Edit Item form etc.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath can also allow you to edit the default form...as well as create rules for